# Using conditional operations in conjuction with INTERSECT in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I trying to write a stored procedure where I would like to test a passed in argument for certain value through an IF/Else statement and ultimately INTERSECT the result with another table. Something like the following as a non-working pseudo example.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Search]
    @Keyword nvarchar(MAX),
    @ClasificationId int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF (@Keyword != null)
        SELECT * FROM Table WHERE [Keyword] LIKE @Keyword
    ELSE 
        SELECT * FROM Table 

    INTERSECT

    IF (@Classification != null)
        SELECT * FROM Table WHERE [ClassificationID] = @ClassificationId
    ELSE 
        SELECT * FROM Table 
END
```

Comment: ClassificationID is a NVARCHAR(MAX)? Unlike most <ID> fields no?

Comment: loool you're right.  Good point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is easier done as a catch all type query - I recommend the dynamic sql approach as done properly: you'll get a good plan for each permutation of query.

Read this:
http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/

Comment: Interesting article.  Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can meet your requirement with a simple modification to each WHERE clause.

```
SELECT 
   * 
FROM 
   Table 
WHERE 
   @keyword IS NULL 
OR [Keyword] LIKE @Keyword
INTERSECT
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  Table 
WHERE 
  @ClassificationId IS NULL 
OR [ClassificationID] = @ClassificationId
```